# How to make product categories tree?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, recursion, tree, fastapi

I use fastapi, postgresDB, I need to create an endpoint that returns tree of product categories

```
class CategoryTree(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    children: list[CategoryTree] | None = None

class ListCategoryTree(RootModel):
    root: list[CategoryTree]
```

The table contains information about product categories (postgres DB)

| Id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 412 | Women | None |
| 723 | Costumes | 412 |
| 9421 | Swimwear | 723 |
| 3 | Men | None |
| 633 | Costumes | 3 |
| 111 | Business suit | 633 |
| 87 | Kids | None |

With sqlalchemy I get all the categories

```
def rec(cat, all_categories):
    if cat.parent is None:
        all_categories.append(CategoryTree(
            id=cat.id,
            name=cat.name,
            children=[]
        ))
    else:
        for parent_cat in all_categories:
            if parent_cat.id == cat.parent:
                parent_cat.children.append(cat)

async def get_category_tree() -> ListCategoryTree:
    categories = await category_pg_service.get_categories()  # request to db
    all_categories = []
    for cat in categories:
        rec(cat, all_categories)
    return ListCategoryTree(root=all_categories)  # pydantic model (final result)

@router.get('', response_model=ListCategoryTree)
async def category_tree() -> ListCategoryTree:
    return await get_category_tree()
```

I managed to get a list of parents and their children, but the children also have children.
I need help with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive pattern is -

```py
async def get_category_tree(parent=None):    
  return [
    {
      'id': cat['id'],
      'name': cat['name'],
      'children': await get_category_tree(cat['id']), # recur
    }
    for cat in await get_categories(parent) # db query
  ]
```

I don't know about your DB, but suppose we can query records by `parent` -

```py
data = [
  { 'id': 412, 'name': 'Women', 'parent': None },
  { 'id': 723, 'name': 'Costumes', 'parent': 412 },
  { 'id': 9421, 'name': 'Swimwear', 'parent': 723 },
  { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Men', 'parent': None },
  { 'id': 633, 'name': 'Costumes', 'parent': 3 },
  { 'id': 111, 'name': 'Business suit', 'parent': 633 },
  { 'id': 87, 'name': 'Kids', 'parent': None },
]

def get_categories(parent=None):
  return mock_query(data, parent=parent)
```

I could now write a `mock_query` to provide a runnable demo -

```py
import asyncio

async def mock_query(data, **kwargs):
  await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # simulate async
  return list(d for d in data if all(k in d and d[k] == v for k, v in kwargs.items()))

async def main():
  print(await get_category_tree()) # build tree

asyncio.run(main())
```

```py
[
  {'id': 412, 'name': 'Women', 'children': [
    {'id': 723, 'name': 'Costumes', 'children': [
      {'id': 9421, 'name': 'Swimwear', 'children': []}
    ]}
  ]},
  {'id': 3, 'name': 'Men', 'children': [
    {'id': 633, 'name': 'Costumes', 'children': [
      {'id': 111, 'name': 'Business suit', 'children': []}
    ]}
  ]},
  {'id': 87, 'name': 'Kids', 'children': []}
]
```

In your own code, that might look something more like this -

```py
async def get_category_tree(parent=None):    
  return ListCategoryTree(root=[
    CategoryTree(
      id=cat['id'],
      name=cat['name'],
      children=(await get_category_tree(cat['id'])).root,
    )
    for cat in await pg_service.get_categories(parent=parent)
  ])

@router.get('', response_model=ListCategoryTree)
async def category_tree() -> ListCategoryTree:
    return await get_category_tree()
```